# Why numpy function empty() only generates zeros?

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to use `empty()` from numpty to generate arrays but something weird happened:

```
empty(3); empty(4); empty(5)
```

always gave arrays of zeros. Even if nonzero numbers(very small ones) occurred for the first time, they became all zeros from the second time, e.g., I typed `empty(5)` for the first time:

```
array([  0.00000000e+000,   0.00000000e+000,   2.12332334e-314,
     2.12517151e-314,   0.00000000e+000])
```

and the second time when I typed `empty(5)`:

```
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

The version of python I'm using is 2.7.

Comment: Were you expecting the results to be random? NumPy makes no promises about what the array contains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html:

> [empty](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html#numpy.empty), unlike [zeros](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html#numpy.zeros), does not set the array values to zero, and may
>   therefore be marginally faster. On the other hand, it requires the
>   user to manually set all the values in the array, and should be used
>   with caution.

There is no guarantee that the values will be anything. The reason the values happen to be zeros is that the memory is uninitialized, so whatever was in that memory beforehand must have left the value at those addresses as zeros (mostly). Essentially, the values will be completely random, but not necessarily distributed evenly.

The question for you is, why do you care what's in an uninitialized array, and why are you even looking at the values in the first place? What do you expect to be happening?

Comment: Thanks so much for the information! I didn't understand this function correctly.

Comment: @Coraine You're welcome! In the future, reading the documentation for anything you're working with is a great way to avoid having to ask obvious questions like this. Also, remember to accept my answer if you feel it's adequate.